# Celeron E3300 vs Celeron 847

Tags: intel-celeron

Any Idea which of those 2 would be faster or will it be about the same ?
The CPUs would be used for websurfing and video streaming mostly, but with a dedicated GPU.

I know the E3300 is older, but its clocked at 2.5Ghz vs 1.1Ghz of the 847.

Comment: I am a bit confused, one of those is for a Mobile and one is Desktop. Are you looking at the two options (a desktop/laptop) or just curious?

Comment: Aye, those CPU's are worlds apart. See http://ark.intel.com/compare/56056,42771

Comment: yes true but theres ITX boards using the 847 now, too.

Comment: I know they are apart - just dont know if the sandy-bridge architecture will win if clocked 1.4Ghz lower ...

Answer (score 1):

The celeron 847 is about two years more recent and uses a more modern design than the E3300. However I sincerely doubt that this will make up the difference between 1.1Ghz (847) vs 2.5GHz.   CPU's do not generally get twice as fast per generation. It is more a 20-30% improvement (at the same clock speed).

Summarised: the E3300 will be faster.

Note that it will also use up to four times the power of the 847.  That is extra heat you need to dissipate, which is a bad thing in a HTPC.

Answer (score 1):

[PassMark - CPU Benchmarks](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php) rates the E3300 at 1641 and the 847 at 1016, so the E3300 is quite a bit faster. Those ratings aren't completely reliable, but if there's a difference that big, it's convincing.

Websurfing alone (without plugins or heavy JavaScript) isn't a CPU intensive task, so you'll most likely won't notice any difference.

With video streaming, it depends. There are codecs which rely almost completely on the GPU, while others make more use of the CPU. With HD videos, that could be a problem, but that probably goes for both CPUs.